# Mocking methods having multiple return values in Play framework 2.5.3

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework, mockito, specs2

I am working in Play 2.5.3 , scala 2.11.7., Akka 2.4.7 .I ma doing Unit Testing using Specs2 and Mockito . I have a method that i need to mock.It returns  multiple 2 string values.
when i am doing this :

```
val mockTokenGenerator = mock[ValidatorClass] mockTokenGenerator.tokenGenerator("testClient") returns ("abc" , "abc")
```

It gives me error : **found :String , required : (String, String)**
`tokenGenerator` is the name of method i  need to mock.
What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: What is multiple string value? `(String, String)`?

Comment: See in actual am calling method like this:   `val (private_key,pub_key) = tokenGenerator(username)` and it returns like `(pubkey,privatekey)`

Comment: What does `multiple 2 string values` mean? My guess is that `returns (("abc" , "abc"))` will solve the issue.

Comment: Wouldn't this suffice?: `val (res1, res2) = mock[ValidatorClass] mockTokenGenerator.tokenGenerator("testClient") returns ("abc" , "abc")`

Comment: @Robert Udah The result of the RHS expression is (shall be) a mocked token generator returning a tuple when called; not a tuple itself. So the answer is 'no'.